# Что за ошибка в MongoDB: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Начал изучать MongoDB с подключением MongoClient. Программа MongoDB на комп установлена, драйвер(mongodb 5.7.0) к проекту подключен. Правда, с авторизацией к самому серверу MongoDB ничего не делал (вроде как ни пароля, ни логина не вводил). Не получается подключиться. Почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какая версия Node у вас?

Comment: node v 13.14.0 на Windows 7

Comment: Так я и думал. На Node версии 13.14.0 ещё нет оператора `??` поэтому он и отказывается работать, установите более старую версию пакета.

Comment: Или версию nodejs поднять...